# Magento 2.4.5: Unable to get Stripe Payment information in my observer class

Tags: magento, events, event-handling, e-commerce, observers

With the upgrade to Magento 2.4.5 from 2.4.2, the old code in an observer class in the custom module to get information about Stripe Payment isn't working any more. It looks like Magento event `sales_order_place_after` isn't able to help with retrieving payment information. I tried several other events including  `sales_order_load_after sales_order_save_before sales_order_save_after sales_order_delete_before sales_order_delete_after checkout_submit_all_after`. Below is the code snippet that calls a function by passing a Stripe payment object and an array containing order details. `$stripePayment->getCard()` returns null although Magento admin shows all payment information.

```
switch ($_payment_info->getMethod()) {
    case "stripe_payments":
        // We need to set the current_order in registry, as StripeIntegration script info.php uses this registry.
        // Instantiate the StripeIntegration Info class after setting the registry.
        $this->registry->register('current_order', $order);
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $stripePayment = $objectManager->get('StripeIntegration\Payments\Block\Adminhtml\Payment\Info');

        // Now, we can make the calls to retrieve the Stripe details for the Credit card.
        $this->get_credit_card_payment_info($order_info, $stripePayment->getCard());
        $order_info["cc_name"] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        $order_info["cc_veri"] = $order->getPayment()->getTransactionId();
        break;
```

The comments in it will help you understand that I'm using registry to store the order object for the Stripe module to use in its class. This has been working fine for the past three years until the latest Magento upgrade.